# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl - no route action, but it's in the routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Update** - typical user error - *guys thanks for all the technical help!  It looks like the password_reset_controller_test should have never been made.  For some reason - my control exists even though there was a "--no-test-framework" used in 12.1.1.  I'm pretty sure I mistyped something & that's why the tutorial doesn't have a ID for the user on it.*  To recap:  the solution was removing the controller test - as there's an integration test made later.

I've got an issue with an error claiming no route, but can clearly see the route in the routes.rb file & in the rake routes.  I'm using Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial guide.  In chapter 12, I've got a failing test. I tested this by removing and adding back several parts - it appears to actually be in the controller, even though it claims no action found.  I also checked for params issues as best as I know how with my limited knowledge.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Thanks ...

```
ERROR["test_should_get_edit", PasswordResetsControllerTest, 2016-10-20 15:24:37 +0000]
 test_should_get_edit#PasswordResetsControllerTest (1476977077.08s)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:         ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets"}
            test/controllers/password_resets_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsControllerTest>'
        test/controllers/password_resets_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsControllerTest>'

  54/54: [=======================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:03, Time: 00:00:03

Finished in 3.02339s
54 tests, 279 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Controller Test

```
password_resets_controller_test
    require 'test_helper'

    class PasswordResetsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

      test "should get new" do
        get :new
        assert_response :success
      end

      test "should get edit" do
        get :edit
        assert_response :success
      end
    end
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root   'static_pages#home'
  get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Controller file

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user,         only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]    # Case (1)

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      @user.update_attribute(:reset_digest, nil)
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
end
```

Here's rake routes file - if I read this right there's an edit option in there ... also the editing of the route file when I remove the resource gets a different error message.

```
rake routes
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
                   root GET    /                                       static_pages#home
                   help GET    /help(.:format)                         static_pages#help
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                        static_pages#about
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                      static_pages#contact
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                       users#new
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                        sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                        sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                       sessions#destroy
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)              password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
             microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)                   microposts#create
              micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)               microposts#destroy
```

Comment: Can you include the failure message you're seeing when you run the tests?

Comment: Yea - sorry - pasted over it!

Comment: @RaptorMan It looks like you haven't provided password reset _id_ (see your `edit_password_reset` route)

Comment: @cema-sp is this something the tutorial would have included in the partials or something that would have been listed in the fixtures?

Comment: You need a User fixture. Then create a user int test: `@user = users(:michael)` and get page with: `get :edit, { id: @user. reset_token }`. See https://www.railstutorial.org/book/password_reset#sec-password_reset_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be passing the required parameter with the request as below:

```
test "should get edit" do
  get :edit, { id: <id-of-the-resource-for-your-controller> }
  assert_response :success
end
```

Comment: This was the best wording of the solution.  The error was indeed generated as the other two people had said - just yours helped me turn around & find my error the best.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `get :edit`, try `get '/password_resets/new'`

To check the route path, run `rake routes` in terminal and see
equivalent paths for `:edit` and `:new` actions.

Comment: I added the update to the bottom of the description ... from what I saw (frustratingly) ... create, new, edit are all present in the route.  I gave up on the rake routes, as when I edit the routes.rb file - the error message is different, telling me the file issue is either beyond my knowledge or located away from the actual routing in routes.rb

Comment: + It would be nice if you could use rspec instead of mini_test. Easy to learn to you'll have great developer support. By the way michael hartl tutorial- rails 4 uses rspec by default. :)

Comment: I tried in both routes.rb & in the controller test, I tried new, then edit, then update like so ...  "get    '/edit',    to: 'password_resets#edit'" with update.  No change thus far.

Comment: I'm using rails 5 tutorial ... I think ... I've heard someone say I should go with pry over rspec & mini ... in this type of situation would rspec be better or worse?  I'm trying to plough through it using the books recommendations the first time...so I won't be installing any extra gems at this point (i'm also nearing the limit of what my cloud9 account will allow me for memory to run at any time) @ajay